# Strip trailing 0s in a binary in Erlang

Tags: binary, erlang, trim, strip

I am currently writing a function in Erlang, which requires binaries which do not have trailing zeros. Due to the implementation, and other inputs the things that will be returned *will* have trailing zeros.

In other words, I will be having things such as:

`<<1,2,3,0,0>>` and `<<3,1,0,2,4,5,0,0,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0>>`

For the above, I need to obtain:

`<<1,2,3>>` and `<<3,1,0,2,4,5,0,0,2,3,4>>`

Zeros before the continuous zeros at the end need to be kept.

If anyone could give a solution it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The simple and straightforward way would be something like:

```
1> Binary = <<3,1,0,2,4,5,0,0,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0>>.
<<3,1,0,2,4,5,0,0,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0>>
2> list_to_binary(lists:reverse(lists:dropwhile(fun(0) -> true; (_) -> false end, lists:reverse(binary_to_list(Binary))))).
<<3,1,0,2,4,5,0,0,2,3,4>>
```

I recommend profiling it with realistic data to see if it'll work for you.

Comment: Also, I realised I could also use this:

trim(A) ->
 case binary:at(A,byte_size(A) - 1) == 0 of
  true -> trim(binary:part(A,{0,byte_size(A)-1}));
  false -> A
 end.

Which means no need to convert to list and back. Anyway, all solved, thank you!

Comment: That's true, but your way also does a lot of unnecessary operations and creates a lot of garbage that has to be cleaned up. As long as the binaries you're dealing with are small and don't have a lot of trailing 0's, you'll be fine, but you still really need to profile both ways with real data before you put this into a real system. Btw, your way also fails on empty binaries or binaries containing all 0's.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I put together before noticing @caluga's similar one in a comment. This one does handle empty binaries or all zeroes.

```
strip(B) ->
  strip(B, erlang:byte_size(B) - 1).

strip(_B, -1) ->
  <<>>;
strip(B, Idx) ->
  case binary:at(B, Idx) of
    0 -> strip(B, Idx - 1);
    _ -> binary:part(B, 0, Idx + 1)
  end.


1> demo:strip(<<>>).
<<>>
2> demo:strip(<<0>>).
<<>>
3> demo:strip(<<0,0>>).
<<>>
4> demo:strip(<<1,2>>).
<<1,2>>
5> demo:strip(<<1,0,2>>).
<<1,0,2>>
6> demo:strip(<<1,0,2,0>>).
<<1,0,2>>
7> demo:strip(<<1,0,2,0,0>>).
<<1,0,2>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple function:

```
-module(strip).

-export([trailing0/1]).

trailing0(B) when is_binary(B) ->
    S = byte_size(B) - 1,
    case B of
        <<Prefix:S/bytes, 0>> -> trailing0(Prefix);
        _ -> B
    end;
trailing0(B) -> error(badarg, [B]).
```

If you expect long suffixes, you can use this:

```
trailing0(B) when is_binary(B) ->
    S = byte_size(B) - 1,
    S2 = S - 7,
    case B of
        <<Prefix:S2/bytes, 0:64>> -> trailing0(Prefix);
        <<Prefix:S/bytes, 0>> -> trailing0(Prefix);
        _ -> B
    end;
trailing0(B) -> error(badarg, [B]).
```